# Bash substring with pipes and stdin

Tags: bash

My goal is to cut the output of a command down to an arbitrary number of characters (let's use **6**). I would like to be able to append this command to the end of a pipeline, so it should be able to just use stdin.

```
echo "1234567890" | your command here 
# desired output: 123456
```

I checked out `awk`, and I also noticed bash has a `substr` command, but both of the solutions I've come up with seem longer than they need to be and I can't shake the feeling I'm missing something easier.

I'll post the two solutions I've found as answers, I welcome any critique as well as new solutions!

---

Solution found, thank you to all who answered!

It was close between jcollado and Mithrandir - I will probably end up using both in the future. Mithrandir's answer was an actual substring and is easier to view the result, but jcollado's answer lets me pipe it to the clipboard with no EOL character in the way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Do you want something like this:

```
echo "1234567890" | cut -b 1-6
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I knew I was missing something. I'll still post my other attempts for posterity and amusement.

Comment: It's funny how you intuited the answer: "My goal is to cut ...".

Answer (score 6):

What about using `head -c/--bytes`?

```
$ echo t9p8uat4ep | head -c 6
t9p8ua
```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite nice as well! Actually, even a bit better since it doesn't include an EOL character.

Answer (score 6):

I had come up with:

```
echo "1234567890" | ( read h; echo ${h:0:6} )
```

and

```
echo "1234567890" | awk '{print substr($0,1,6)}'
```

But both seemed like I was using a sledgehammer to hit a nail.

Comment: is that meant to be | ( read h; echo ${h:0:6} ) in the first example ?

Comment: Honestly, I can't really remember. I just tried it again now and it works both ways for me in zsh, but in bash only seems to work with parentheses. So I guess maybe it is, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
printf "%.6s" 1234567890
123456
```

Answer (score 0):

If `your_command_here` is `cat`:

```
% OUTPUT=t9p8uat4ep
% cat <<<${OUTPUT:0:6}
t9p8ua
```

Comment: The only problem with this is I did want something I could append on to the end of a pipeline, something that was able to just use stdin. I will edit the question to make that clearer.